# How to convert string json to JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

How can I convert this string into JSONArray ?

```
{"result":{"passion":[{"id":2,"description":"Sushi"},{"id":3,"description":"Dinner"},{"id":4,"description":"Sex"},{"id":5,"description":"Boobies"},{"id":6,"description":"Sleep"},{"id":7,"description":"Cars"},{"id":8,"description":"Travel"},{"id":9,"description":"Soccer"},{"id":10,"description":"Silice"}]}}
```

I'm trying to do:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("passion");
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for passion
```

Comment: There must be something you aren't showing us. Are you trying to access a JSON element named `interest` anywhere?

Comment: those are a mans passions right?

Comment: how do you get your `jsonObject`?

Comment: I've fixed it. Just need to create a new instance JSONObject

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject values = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");    
    JSONArray jsonArray = values.getJSONArray("passion");

Answer (score 2):

is seems like you are not getting `result`  object

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject. getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("passion");
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this is what you need dear

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
 JSONObject resultValues = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result"); 
 JSONArray passionArray = resultValues.getJSONArray("passion")
```